# Is there a way to import Products and Opportunities in Salesforce Essentials?

Tags: import, data-import-wizard

I can see that you can import Accounts and Contacts, but I don't see a way to import a CSV of Products, or even past Opportunities so my reporting would be right.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Not completely sure but [looks like](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/sales-cloud/) products are **not** supported in essentials. Do you have it with your edition?

Comment: I can add products, but I have to do it by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, Essentials does not include any API or integrations, so you can't import anything that the import wizards do not support. Based on my limited understanding of Essentials, you could trick the import wizard into importing opportunities by

(a) creating a Custom Object,
(b) creating a Process Builder that
   creates related Opportunity records, then
(c) importing to the
   Custom Object.

However, I'm also under the impression that you can request API access temporarily (read: a few days) to import your data, or even pay a nominal fee to have salesforce.com import your data for you. To find out what options are available to you, please contact your Account Executive or Technical Support for additional information on the current policies and options for loading historical sales data in Essentials.

Comment: It's annoying but understandable that I can't import my past history.  But why would they not allow me to just import my products and a single price book to get started?  Seems like an odd decision, or maybe there's something I don't understand going on here.

Comment: @ScottCWilson I've always felt that it was weird to have this particular limitation in the lower editions (previously Group Edition). One of the main draws of a CRM, obviously, is to be able to report on sales, so not being able to import past sales is an obviously painful limitation. This is one of the reasons why I couldn't, and wouldn't, recommend the lower editions to anyone, as they're just too limited.

Comment: Seems like [dataloader.io](https://dataloder.io) is the way to go for folks in my situation.

Comment: I tried asking the AE to turn on API for a client, and we both found out today that it's Pro+ https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326486 -- but yes that IS sweet that dl.io can do its thing without API (because that data import wizard is NOT perfect).